# Monte Carlo Simulation Fails to Recognize Connected Graph

Tags: python, algorithm, math, graph, montecarlo

I'm writing a Monte Carlo Simulation that calculates the expected value for the minimum number of directed edges needed to make an n vertex graph connected. It does this by starting with an all 0 adjacency matrix,adding a single directed edge and the then testing the matrix to see if it represents a connected graph. This process is looped until a connected graph is constructed, and then the number of iterations it took to get there is the sample size for a single trial. The program seems to be accurate for small graphs, but once the graphs exceed ~10 vertices, it becomes increasingly clear that it keeps adding vertices after a connected graph has already been constructed. Essentially, the algorithm is not stopping early enough on large graphs.

It seems that the likely culprit would be the isConnected function, but I am not entirely sure. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import math
import random

# Randomly adds an edge to the graph by
# choosing a random 0 from the adjecency
# matrix and changing it to a 1.
# @param mat - the list type matrix
# @param k   - the dimension of the matrix
def addEdge(mat, k):

    flag = False

    while flag == False:

        colNum = random.randint(0, k-1)
        rowNum = random.randint(0, k-1)

        if mat[rowNum][colNum] == 0:
            mat[rowNum][colNum] = 1
            flag = True 

# Runs singleTrial multiple times and finds
# the average of their sample sizes
def getExpectedValue(size, trials):

    sampleSum = 0.0

    flag = True

    for i in range(trials):
        sample = singleTrial(size)
        sampleSum += sample

    expectedValue = float(sampleSum/trials)

    return expectedValue


# Adds edges to an initially edgeless
# graph UNTIL the graph becomes connected.
def singleTrial(size):

    # Create all zero matrix
    mat = np.random.randint(0,1,size=(size,size))

    sample = 0

    flag = True

    while flag:
        # Uncomment this code to see each matrix that is 
        # generated in a single trial. Upon viewing it
        # is clear that this while loop does not terminate
        # early enough.
        #print mat
        #print "\n"
        addEdge(mat, size)
        sample += 1
        if isConnected(mat, size):
            print mat
            flag = False

    print sample
    return sample 


# Checks if a given matrix is connected by
# calculating the sum of the number of 1 step
# paths though the number of k step paths
# for every pair of verticies. If this number
# is zero for any pair, then the graph is 
# not connected.
def isConnected(A, k):

    B = A

    for i in range(2, k-1):
        B = B + np.linalg.matrix_power(A, i)
    if np.prod(B) != 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False


if __name__ == '__main__' :


    # Perform 1 trial on an 11 vertex graph
    print getExpectedValue(11, 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue. I used the function numpy.prod(mat) to check whether the matrix contained a zero because it returns the product of all the entries in the matrix. I did not consider the possibility of overflow. I assume that if the value of numpy.prod becomes too large (which it most certainly would), it will reset to zero. This would create many false negatives.

Comment: Why were you using np.prod(B) instead of (B == 0).any()?

Comment: Well this was for a python school project, and my teacher who is more of a math guy suggested the use of prod(). Though I brought the issue to his attention and it has been resolved. I just started learning python, so I did not know about the any() function. Thanks for the tip.